# Get Facebook Post images from Facebook Graph API v2.6

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to update a client's code which pulled user's images from Facebook graph API.

I would like to pull the all the items from '/me/feed' if possible, but reading the SDK docs it looks like the feed is separate from the photos now.
The original client used v2.2 and would return a property images containing an array of images that were tied to the post.

```
"images": [
    {
      "height": 960,
      "source": "https://scontent.xx...",
      "width": 720
    },
    {
      "height": 800,
      "source": "https://scontent.xx...",
      "width": 600
    },
...
]
```

With v2.6 it seems the most I can get is a cover photo using full_picture as a field. '/me/feed?fields=id,message,full_picture,created_time' but this neglects the four other images on the post. There is a separate photos edge but it doesn't appear to have any way to just get the images for a specific post.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to go about getting all feed items and their corresponding images. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same images by doing another query on the object_id. NOTE: This is different then the actual id, which is what I was searching on before

- From /me/feed?fields=id,object_id
- From /{object_id}?fields=images